# preventDefault on hover not working on Android?

Tags: jquery, android, mobile

I have the following piece of code:

```
$('#a').hover(function(e) {
$(this).parent().children('ul').show();
e.preventDefault();
});
```

It prevents the link from navigating on iOS but not on Android, any ideas why?

For full code please see here: https://tinker.io/ff4ab/6

Thanks
Pete